# i want to change variable value but all i want memory address will stay same, how can i do that

Tags: c++, c

```
int x=5;
int &time=x;
int *ptr_x = &time;

while(1)
    cout << (*ptr_x) << endl;
    (*ptr_x)++;
```

i want to change "variable value" but all i want "address" will stay same, how can i do that –

Comment: You started with complex langage like C++ without reading a book. It is not possible to learn language using try and guess method (plus SO post) voting to close

Comment: @cdhowie `(*ptr_x)++` increments the value, not the pointer. And it's outside the loop.

Comment: if i increase the value will the adress wtill samei need to find out that

Comment: You can print the address with `std::cout << ptr_x`.

Comment: sorry dude ii am not parrot @__P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Whats the difference between incrementing pointers value and the value of the pointer?

1. **Increment pointer's value** It means you have a pointer *pointing* to a value. You increase *the value*. The fact that there is something pointing to it is "accidental".
2. **Increment the value of the pointer** It means you have a pointer pointing to something, and by increasing the value of the pointer you change the direction to which it points. I.e. you're not pointing to that value anymore, you are pointing to something totally different now. If you have an array, if you are pointing to an element in the array and increase the pointer in [size of element stored in array], you'll end up pointing to the next element.

Hope this helps!

Comment: pointers pointed value vs variable value, if i increase variable will the address change??

Comment: If you increase *ptr, the you'd be changing the value. If you increase ptr, you'll be changing the address.

Comment: i want to increase variable value without changing memory address

Comment: Ok, increase *ptr then!

Comment: so this will happens at the same address right?

Comment: Yes, the pointed address won't be changed

Answer (score 2):

> Whats the difference between incrementing pointers value and the value of the pointer?

Pointer's value is the value of the pointer. There is no difference between these two.

Indirecting through a pointer to get a reference to the pointed value, and incrementing that pointed value modifies the pointed value.

Incrementing the value of the pointer changes the value of the pointer, i.e. it will point to another object. Specifically, it will point to the next sibling of the originally pointed element of an array.

Comment: this will be pointers pointed value vs the variable value

Answer (score 1):

If you increment the pointer variable it will then point to something else. If you increment what the pointer points to the pointer variable will still point to the same thing, but that thing will have been incremented.

A pointer is basically a sign saying "the thing is over there". If you increment the pointer you are changing the sign to make "over there" something else. If you dereference the pointer and increment, then you are basically following the instructions on the sign and then incrementing whatever is "over there", but the sign is unchanged.

Comment: i want to change variable value but all i want value of address will stay  same, how can i do that

Comment: Why has this answer been downvoted? :think: